# Nature of the set of deltas in limit definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, intuition, epsilon-delta

I was proving the fact that if f is differentiable at a, then (c*f)’(a)=c*f(a)’
After showing it, I started to play with some ideas and wondered from intuition how to see that depending on the value of the constant (magnitude actually), f might be more or less nicely differentiable at that point. To define what I meant by nice , I refer to how close you have to be around a in order to ensure you are “epsilon-good” in the limit definition for the secant slope and f’(a) and c*f’(a) respectively. Now, following the principle that in most cases, taking smaller epsilons lead to smaller deltas (unless perhaps you subtract a negligible amount to the next epsilon you choose) I did the following:
Suppose f tends to l near a.
Now, c*f tends to cl near a, but moreover, to be epsilon-good for c*f you need to make sure that f is epsilon/|c| good. So, when this is bigger than epsilon (when |c| <1) the deltas to be epsilon-good for c*f will be (probably) greater than the ones for f (the opposite happens when |c| >1). Now, to make this idea more solid, I had the following follow up doubt that I would also love to add and make clear:
When talking about the set of deltas that ensure you are epsilon-good in any definition of limits in real analysis, call it D, I wonder if this sets are always semi open that is: (0,c] or if sometimes they have to be open : (0,c). I have this question because when making the previous comments, I always assumed that these delta sets had a maximum. I know they have a sup in any case. (open or semi) by the Lu property. However , the thing is whether or not this sup would belong to D. I hope I made everything clear and someone can carefully clear my mind and describe this tiny yet nice remarks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite hard to read. I think this sort of answers what you're asking:

Let $U$ be any nonempty set, $a\in U$ fixed. Say $f:U\to\Bbb R$ is some function such that $\lim_{x\to a\\x\in U}f(x)$ exists and equals $L$. Fix $\epsilon>0$.

Define $D:=\{\delta>0:\forall x\in U\cap(a-\delta,a+\delta)\setminus\{a\},\,|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\}$. You want to know if $D$ looks like an open or half open interval.

The answer is that $D=(0,c]$ for some $c$ *or* $D=(0,\infty)$. Because the limit exists, $D$ is nonempty. Notice that if $\delta\in D$ and $0<\delta'<\delta$ then $\delta'\in D$ too; $D$ is downward closed, so it must in fact be an interval of some kind. If $D$ is unbounded, then $D=(0,\infty)$. Suppose $D$ is bounded.

Let $c=\sup D$. This is the least upper bound; if $0<\delta<c$ then $\delta$ is not an upper bound for $D$, thus there exists some $\delta'\in D$ with $\delta<\delta'$. It follows $\delta\in D$. So, $D$ contains $(0,c)$. If $\delta>c$, then $\delta$ is a strict upper bound of all elements of $D$ so cannot itself be in $D$. The last thing to check is whether or not $c$ is in $D$.

Suppose $x\in U\setminus\{a\}$ has $|x-a|<c$. Then there is some $\delta>0$ with $|x-a|<\delta<c$, and as established $\delta\in D$ must hold and then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ too. Therefore, $c\in D$.

Therefore $D=(0,c]$.